# Python script to copy some messages from slack which were posted in some time range

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

I want to write a python script using some slack API's which will be able to copy some messages which were pasted between say 10AM to 11AM in a `channel A` & then paste the same messages in a different `channel B`.

I know that it's easy to write a message in slack via a python script, but is it also possible to pull some messages out of slack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use Requests (or any http client you like) with this endpoint: https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history

This returns a list of messages for a given channel that you can filter with the `oldest` and `latest` arguments.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be nice , & by request you mean http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ ? right??

Comment: Absolutely - if you want something present in the standard library you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html or https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html if you're on Python 2.x